# Why my Midlet "Paused" during phone locked?

Tags: java-me, midlet, wav

Why is my Midlet not running during phone locked ? ##

I am new to J2ME. I successfully created a Midlet application to play `.wav` files. But while my Midlet is running, I unintentionally pressed my phone lock button and my phone was locked. Then my Midlet stopped playing sound.

Why has that occured?

How do I make my Midlet continue playing sound while the phone is locked?

I run my application on my Samsung Star.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer _Thanks Mr.Joachim for your correction, sorry for my english :) –

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell us which operating system your phone comes with?
Can you see the app running when you unlock the phone?

I'm guessing that the application has gone into destroy mode

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I don't know what OS on my phone but i think it's .[java](http://www.mobile88.com/cellphone/Samsung/Samsung-Star-S5233/specification.asp). Yes when i unlock the phone, my app start to playing sound again as before. I think this like on paused state. How about you?  Sorry for my english.

Comment: If it starts playing again after its unlocked, it was in paused state.

Comment: Samsung phones usually have Bada or symbian

Comment: I was found on another thread [http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/309408-j2me-suspended-when-phone-locked/page__p__1790668__fromsearch__1&#entry1790668]_italic_, if somes phones does not let java apps run on the background.